# Jump to function definition in Emacs + Slime/leiningen-Swank + Clojure

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime, leiningen

I'm using Emacs with clojure mode and slime connected to a swank server produced by running `lein swank` and would really love to be able to **easily jump to function definitions within my project**. Can I do this with out having to manually rebuild tags every time I change branches?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using SLIME this can be done easily with `M-.`

EDIT: When Clojure code is compiled the location of definitions is stored. Note that this works best when you compile entire files. Jumping to an definition that you evaluated with C-x C-e doesn't work so well (tho it does works for Common Lisp and SLIME).

Comment: well that was easy :) almost anticlimactic. but How does it work?

Comment: note: the . at the end of the answer is not marking the end of the sentence its part of the answer. thats alt-period.

Comment: I took the liberty of indicating the above with typography.

Comment: Note that `M-,` will bring you back to where you came from, after using `M-.` to go to a definition.